# TForm management in Spring4D

Tags: delphi, spring4d

I have the following code:

Project.dpr

```
program Project2;

uses
  madExcept,
  madLinkDisAsm,
  madListHardware,
  madListProcesses,
  madListModules,
  Spring.Container,
  Vcl.Forms,
  uRegistrations in '..\Memory leak II\uRegistrations.pas',
  Unit3 in 'Unit3.pas' {MainForm},
  Unit4 in 'Unit4.pas' {SecondaryForm},
  Unit5 in 'Unit5.pas';

{$R *.res}

begin
  RegisterTypes(GlobalContainer);
  Application.Initialize;
  Application.MainFormOnTaskbar := True;
//  MainForm:=TMainForm.Create(nil);
  Application.CreateForm(TMainForm, MainForm);
  MainForm.SecondaryForm := Globalcontainer.Resolve<ISecondaryForm>;
  Application.Run;
end.
```

uRegistrations.pas that registers the interface

```
unit uRegistrations;

interface

uses
  Spring.Container;

procedure RegisterTypes(Container: TContainer);

implementation

uses
  Unit5,
  Unit4;

procedure RegisterTypes(Container: TContainer);
begin
  container.RegisterType<ISecondaryForm, TSecondaryForm>.DelegateTo(
    function: TSecondaryForm
    begin
      result := TSecondaryForm.Create(nil);
    end);
  Container.Build;

end;

end.
```

Unit3.pas holding the main form

```
unit Unit3;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows,
  Winapi.Messages,
  System.SysUtils,
  System.Variants,
  System.Classes,
  Vcl.Graphics,
  Unit5,
  Vcl.Controls,
  Vcl.Forms,
  Vcl.Dialogs;

type
  TMainForm = class(TForm)
  private
    { Private declarations }
    FSecondaryForm: ISecondaryForm;
  public
    { Public declarations }
    property SecondaryForm: ISecondaryForm read FSecondaryForm write FSecondaryForm;
  end;

var
  MainForm: TMainForm;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

end.
```

Unit4.pas with the secondary form

```
unit Unit4;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  unit5,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs;

type
  TSecondaryForm = class(TForm, ISecondaryForm)
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

//var
//  SecondaryForm: TSecondaryForm;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

end.
```

and finally Unit5.pas with the Interface declaration

```
{$M+}
unit Unit5;

interface

type
ISecondaryForm=interface
  ['{62D63E9A-A3AD-435B-8938-9528E70D78B1}']
end;

implementation

end.
```

It compiles and runs regularly but when I close the application i have three memory leaks.

> allocation number: 8482 program up time: 721 ms type: Brush Handle
>   handle: $461027f5 style: BS_SOLID color: $f0f0f0
>
> allocation number: 8318 program up time: 697 ms type: TSecondaryForm
>   address: $d51ac64 size: 924 access rights: read/write
>
> allocation number: 8267 program up time: 693 ms type: Font Handle
>   handle: $1d0a28f1 face: Tahoma height: -11

Why does this happens and how can I solve it ?

**EDIT**

After the answer, I implemented the following solutions (the comments highlight the errors I got:

```
procedure RegisterTypes(Container: TContainer);
begin
  container.RegisterType<ISecondaryForm, TSecondaryForm>.DelegateTo(
    function: TSecondaryForm
    begin
      result := TSecondaryForm.Create(nil);

      result.Owner:=Application.MainForm;//cannot assign to a read-only property
      result.Parent:=Application; //incompatible types
      result.Parent:=application.MainForm;//memory leak

    end);
  Container.Build;

end;
```

I have also tried to amend the OnClose method of TSecondaryForm in the following way:

```
procedure TSecondaryForm.FormClose(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
begin
  Action:=caFree; //memory leak
end;
```

but I got a memory leak.

What am I doing wrong with all the technique above ?

In the end I just made the two methods **_AddRef** and **_Release** manage the reference counting as suggested in the comments and I have no more memory leaks.

```
  TSecondaryForm = class(TForm, ISecondaryForm)
  private
    { Private declarations }
  protected
    FRefCount: Integer;
    function _AddRef: Integer; stdcall;
    function _Release: Integer; stdcall;
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

function TSecondaryForm._AddRef: Integer;
begin
  Result := InterlockedIncrement(FRefCount);
end;

function TSecondaryForm._Release: Integer;
begin
  Result := InterlockedDecrement(FRefCount);
  if Result=0 then
    self.Free;
end
```

Comment: take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20386734/will-an-interface-implementing-form-free-itself-when-there-are-no-more-reference and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/769329/bypassing-disabling-delphis-reference-counting-for-interfaces

Comment: Pass the owner in the constructor, not nil

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want a form (or any class that inherits from TComponent) to be handled by interface reference counting then you need to implement it yourself (look at `System.TInterfacedObject` as an example of how to do it).

You basically need to reimplement `IInterface` to the class you want to enable reference counting on:

```
type
  TInterfacedForm = class(TForm, IInterface)
    // look at System.TInterfacedObject
  end;
```

If you are doing so, keep in mind that it then should not be handled by the owner mechanism. If you register it to the container and use its default creation mechanism it will pass nil to the owner as of Spring4D 1.2 - see `Spring.Container.Resolvers.TComponentOwnerResolver`). In any version before you need to explicitly create it with nil inside of `DelegateTo`.

If you are dealing with any controls over interfaces that are put onto other controls (like frames) via their parent property keep also in mind that in such case another memory management mechanism comes into play which might destroy such a component if its parent is getting destroyed - if you are just dealing with interfaced forms that is not a problem but I thought I mention it here for completeness.

Answer (score 1):

`TComponent` descendants (like `TForm`) disable interfaces reference counting, hence nobody is freeing the secondary form. The memory model is owner based, that is, when the parent object that owns an object is freed, it frees all it's children.

So, you could either pass an owner to the form on the factory function (maybe `Application`, or `Application.MainForm`) and adhere to TComponent's memory model or add a hook on the `OnClose` event of the form and set `Action` to `caFree`. The former will destroy the form when the application is closed, and the latter will destroy it as soon as the secondary form is closed (as soon as possible)